# Removing an item from an array stored in state, delete button (line 55) am i missing a parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Code is in app component (I know that's bad) help would be greatly appreciated. I don't know what I'm doing. Everything works at least except for delete button, trying to remove an item from the list after its been added and can't figure it out. They're asking me to add more details but I don't really know what else to say.

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    
    function App() {
      const [memories, setMemories] = useState([]);
      const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState('');
      const dateAndTime = new Date();
      const dateString = dateAndTime.toLocaleDateString();
      const [allowSubmit, setAllowSubmit] = useState(false);
    
      const handleSubmit = (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        if (allowSubmit === true) {
          setMemories([...memories,{
            id : memories.length,
            value : newItem,
            date : dateString
          }]);
          setNewItem('');
          setAllowSubmit(false);
          }
        }
      const clearAllMemories = () => {
        setMemories([]);
        localStorage.setItem('memories',JSON.stringify(memories));
      }
      useEffect(() => {
        const memoriesData = localStorage.getItem('memories');
        if (memoriesData) {
          setMemories(JSON.parse(memoriesData));
        }
      },[]);
      useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('memories',JSON.stringify(memories));
      });
      return (
        <div className='App'>
          <h2>Favorite moments of the day</h2>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <textarea className='text-area'
              type='text'
              value={newItem}
              onChange={e => {
                setAllowSubmit(true);
                setNewItem(e.target.value)
              }}
              />
            <input className='input-button'type="submit" value="Add Memory"/>
          </form>
          <h3 className='memories-title'>Memories</h3>
          <div className='memories'>
            <ul className='ul'>
              {memories.map(memories => (
              <li key = {memories.id}>{memories.date}{memories.value}
               <button onClick={() => {
                setMemories(memories.value.split(memories.value, 1));
               }}>delete</button>
              </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div> <br/>
          <button className='clear-button'
           onClick={clearAllMemories}
          >
            Clear All Memories
          </button>
        </div>
        );
      }
    export default App;
```

Comment: Add info about why it doesn't, specifically what's the incorrect behaviour you're seeing, do you get any errors and if so what's the specific error message and what line it occurs, etc. Saying "it doesn't work" isn't really useful. As for your actual question, you treat `memories` like an object, referencing `memories.value` multiple time. However, `memories` is an **array**. Also, there's not `.split` method for arrays, if you want to remove the object with that specific value, use `.filter`, e.g. `setMemories(memories.filter(memory => memory.value !== value));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing something that could be the problem.

```
<ul className='ul'>
  {memories.map(memories => (
  <li key = {memories.id}>{memories.date}{memories.value}
    <button onClick={() => {
       setMemories(memories.value.split(memories.value, 1));
       }}>delete</button>
  </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

When using the `map` function with the `memories` array, you're assigning the array's name to the array element. And then you access `memories.value.split` (even though it still doesn't much sense) on the `onClick` callback of the button, wanting to access the array, but probably accessing the array element.

You should give the array element a different name, like `memory` or `memoryElement`, to avoid confusion.

When calling the `split` function (which from looking to the arguments I think you meant to write `splice`) you would call it directly in the `memories` array, not `memories.value`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have understood the problem well, but this could be a solution?

```
<ul className='ul'>
  {memories.map(memory => (
  <li key = {memory.id}>{memory.date}{memory.value}
  <button onClick={() => {
   setMemories([...memories.filter(m => memory.id !== m.id)]);
   }}>delete</button>
  </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```